# php - Clean user input using preg_replace_callback and ord()?

Tags: php, sanitize, preg-replace-callback, sanitization

I have a forum style text box and I would like to sanitize the user input to stop potential xss and code insertion. I have seen htmlentities used, but then others have said that &,#,%,: characters need to be encoded as well, and it seems the more I look, the more potentially dangerous characters pop up. Whitelisting is problematic as there are many valid text options beyond ^a-zA-z0-9. I have come up with this code. Will it work to stop attacks and be secure? Is there any reason not to use it, or a better way?

```
function replaceHTML ($match) {
    return "&#" . ord ($match[0]) . ";";
}

$clean = preg_replace_callback ( "/[^ a-zA-Z0-9]/", "replaceHTML", $userInput );
```

EDIT:***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**
I could of course be wrong, but it is my understanding that htmlentities only replaces & < > " (and ' if ENT_QUOTES is turned on). This is probably enough to stop most attacks (and frankly probably more than enough for my low traffic site). In my obsessive attention to detail, however, I dug further. A book I have warns to also encode # and % for "shutting down hex attacks". Two websites I found warned against allowing : and --. Its all rather confusing to me, and led me to explore converting all non-alphanumeric characters. If htmlentities does this already then great, but it does not seem to. Here are results from code I ran I copied after clicking view source in firefox.

original (random characters to test):
**5:**gjla#''*&$!j-l:4

preg_replace_callback:
<b>5:</b>gjla<hi>#''*&$!j-l:4

htmlentities (w/ ENT_QUOTES):
<b>5:</b>gjla<hi>#''*&$!j-l:4

htmlentities appears to not be encoding those other characters like :
Sorry for the wall of text. Is this just me being paranoid?

EDIT #2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

Comment: You only need to escape quotes and angle brackets. The other special characters just need escaping in case they encounter unquoted html attributes.

Comment: Stop being paranoid, `htmlentities()` (tries to) replace all characters that have an HTML entity representation, it is enough to stop **all** XSS attacks, the same goes for `htmlspecialchars()` as long as you use `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: thank you, I just need to hear it :). Its hard being self taught and paranoid, with a lot of conflicting information all over.

Comment: @user1008960: Please pick an answer and accepted it if this is solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what htmlentities does already:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/NDZMa3

It will convert (spaced to prevent stackoverflow double encoding):
"& # amp ;"
to
"& # amp; # amp ;"

Comment: it is my understanding that htmlentities only changes < > & " (and ' if ENT_QUOTES is turned on), not all non alphanumeric characters - see output on edited main post. Is this correct?

Comment: htmlspecialchars() does only that set of translations, htmlentities will do full entity translation.  Really, either one of these will do the job.  You don't need anything else or someone would have fixed them or created a new function that does exactly what these should be doing - which is to help prevent injection.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to stop XSS attacks is use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: htmlentities is the same as htmlspecialchars: "This function [htmlentities()] is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities."

Comment: @evan: They aren't the same, `htmlspecialchars()` does a lot less but still manages to defeat all XSS attacks.

Comment: Well, that quote is directly from http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: From htmlspecialchars: "Note that this function does not translate anything beyond what is listed above. For full entity translation, see htmlentities()."

Comment: @evan: That's why I said it does a lot less. =) Still, it's enough to stop all XSS vectors.

Comment: @evan: Unless of course, you're injecting the encoded string directly into certain tag attributes, but if that's the case `htmlentities()` won't save you either...

Answer (score 0):

space `' '` can be changed to `\s` in your regex, also by adding `/i` at the end of the regex you made it `case insensitive`, and you don't need manually translate your chars to sequences, it can be done with a callback of [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)

```
$clean = preg_replace_callback('/[^a-z0-9\s]/i', 'htmlentities', $userInput);
```

Comment: This answer is crap. You've just posted meaningless code with not even an attempt at an explanation.

Comment: I've made minimal changes, everything I changed already explained by other commentors, nevertheless, thanks for your opinion

Comment: It's not working, because the callback gets passed an array, yet htmlentitites expects a string parameter. And it still wouldn't escape *all* input values, just what a regular htmlentities() call might convert.